# Is possible to set onclick function in HTML title tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I want to show popup window while user click on browser title portion. I tried to set onclick event in HTML title tag.

Is any other different ways is there to achieve this feature?

Tried code is :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title onclick="show_popup();">Test</title>
    <script>
      function show_popup(){
          //pop up window code.
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup_window"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is not a visible element to click, so it can't have UI behavior like click events etc.

Also, the content of the title element is displayed outside of the html page (on the browser tab or in the browser header bar), so you can't interact with it in JavaScript.

Comment: Besides the fact that you can actually use global attributes on it, like `id="something"` and then get its `innerHTML` for example, as mentioned here, you cannot interact with it, due to the browsers not supporting this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `onclick` attribute on the `title` element, since that attribute is [allowed in all elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes), according to HTML5 CR. Whether it has an effect is a different matter.

The `title` element is [not presented](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#hidden-elements) in the document by default, making it impossible to click on it. It is possible to change this with CSS:

```
head, title { display: block }
```

In modern browsers, this will make the `title` element visible, and clickable.

There is little reason to do so, though. To show something visibly on a page, it is much better to use normal content inside the `body` element.

The rendering of the [`title`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) element content *outside the document area* in a browser window, e.g. in a top bar or in a tab, is a completely different issue and not something that HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or DOM specifications deal with. It is normally not possible to control it in any way; if there is a way in a particular environment, it would be browser-dependent.

Comment: Nice . Can you provide any url links for this? please.

Comment: Added some links to HTML5 CR.